# Upside down orientation doesn't work when set in Info.plist file

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

In my Info.plist file, I set the `Supported Interface orientations` to the 4 offered possibilities, including the `Portrait (top home button)`.

When I run my app, nothing happens when I turn my device upside down. For landscape it's fine.

If in the `.plist` file I select only `Portrait (bottom home button)` then only the normal portrait works (which makes sense), and then prove the `.plist` file is working.

If in one of my `UIViewController` I override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` like this:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
}
```

then it works (only for this `UIViewController`).

So why, as I specified it in my `Info.plist`, I cannot have my app running in Portrait upside down? If it is ignored, what's the point to give it as a choice in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html):

> The easiest way to set an app’s app’s supported interface orientations is to edit the project’s Info.plist file. As in the case of the view controller, you define which of the four interface orientations are permitted. For more information, see Information Property List Key Reference.
>
> If you restrict the app’s supported orientations, then those restrictions apply globally to all of the app’s view controllers, even when your app uses system view controllers. At any given time, the mask of the topmost view controller is logically ANDed with the app’s mask to determine what orientations are permitted. The result of this calculation must never be 0. If it is, the system throws a UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientationException exception.

So, an orientation has to be allowed by the application AND by the view controller to occur.

Comment: I missed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to a controller

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [super supportedInterfaceOrientations] | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```